# Rails Custom parameter on form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to add a functionality to group using scaffold form_for.

```
<%= f.select(:add, @funcionalidades_all.collect{|f| [f.name, f.id]}, { :include_blank => true, :selected => nil}) %>
```

how can I pass selected f.id to a custom params? When I click I want to call add method with this new param...any idea?

Tks

Comment: use hidden_field_tag and javascript to update it when your f.select changes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `pass selected f.id a custom params`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code reuturns just an array of arrays:

```
@funcionalidades_all.collect{|f| [f.name, f.id]}
=>
[["name_1",1],["name_2",2]]
```

Adding custom elements should solve it:

```
<% options= @funcionalidades_all.collect{|f| [f.name, f.id]} %>
<% options += [["custom_1",101],["custom_2",102]] %>

<%= f.select(:add, options, { :include_blank => true, :selected => nil}) %>
```

Consider also creating a helper function to make your view code more clean.

```
<%= f.select(:add, my_options_helper(@funcionalidades_all), { :include_blank => true, :selected => nil}) %>
```